# How to share Ruby Cli executable and make it available globally in command line?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface

At my school we need to perform certain tasks and i've made ruby program that solves the problems and assists. It executes fine but i've to type path to the folder or be in the folder of ruby program.

I'd like to do two things with cli app...

1) make it available to rest of my friends (preferably if they do something like gem install nameOfMyThing)

2) and i and everyone else who downloads it should be able to run it from terminal anywhere whether be on desktop or at c:

Answer (score 0):

To make it available as a gem, you should create a gem. Bundler can help setup all the parts:

```
bundle gem my_gem
```

See more here: http://bundler.io/v1.10/rubygems.html

To make an executable, add a ruby script in "./bin/" then edit you "my_gem.gemspec" file, and add a line about 'executables'.

```
s.executables << 'myscript'  # should exist in bin/myscript
```

http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable

Once you have that working, you can publish your gem using the rake task bundler setup for you:

```
bundle exec rake release
```

That will tag and push to rubygems, and you should then be able to run "gem install my_gem" from any other machine.